Prevent top of element CSS animated appearing from behind other element
I have this CSS
.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.label {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1
}
.desc {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.hideDesc {
  animation: descHide 1s forwards;
}
@keyframes descHide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

for this HTML
  <div class="text">
    <div class="label">
      <p>A Label</p>
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
      <p>Lots of text here...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

Then I'm triggering the CSS animation when you click on .label using some code. The animation raises .desc up, behind .label, as it fades it out.
The issue that I'm having is that you can see the top of .desc above .label as it moves up. How can I animate it so it looks like it's sliding up but into .label ie without any part appearing above .label?

Couldyou explain a bit more what 'above label' means? If it means 'above the element .label' then you can do it with a clip-path on .text but as there is a bit of space above the actual text in .label it doesn't exactly look as tho' .desc is being absorbed into .label. Do you in fact want it to disappear completely when it hits the bottom of the text in label?

Yes, I meant 'above the element .label', Ideally I want it to look like .desc is sliding up into an imaginary slot that runs along the bottom of .label. .desc doesn't distort it slides up and disappears. clip-path seems like something worth trying, thanks.

Any reason not to give .label a solid background color?

No reason. What difference would it make? I'm only concerned with how, when sliding an element up, the top of it appears above the element it slid under.
